# вопрос по загрузке данных

Tags: android

Добрый день, получаю данные через `AsyncTask`, добавляю на сайт одно событие которое нужно будет отобразить в приложении, далее захожу в приложение вижу что оно отображается всё как нужно всё правильно, далее добавляю на сайт ещё одно событие, захожу в приложение заново, он показывает мне уже 2 события, но после не выходя из приложения я обновляю его с помощью `SwipeRefreshLayout` и у меня остается 1 событие, но через какое то время если я захожу и выхожу что то делаю в приложении после обновлении уже 2 события появляется.
Возможно ли что данные отправляются куда то в `cache`  он помнит первую загрузку только, ? в чем может быть причина, как при обновлении может чистить cache либо ещё есть какие то варианты?? хоты бы куда копать дальше

Comment: А код где? И кстати, AsyncTask для сетевых запросов - олдфаг

Comment: какую альтернативу можно использовать вместо AsyncTask?

Comment: Любую библиотеку для работы сетевыми запросами, советую Retrofit

Comment: Не понятно, что вы вовсе хотите!

Comment: Что куда кешируется, как обновляется и отображается - целиком Ваша заслуга, то есть все проблемы в коде, но пока мы его не видим - помочь Вам нечем.